# Repeat values in 1D array across multiple dimensions

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 1 dimensional array of CO2 values where I need to repeat each value over lon/lat dimensions [360, 720] creating an array of dims [365, 360, 720] - i.e. 1 year of daily CO2 values across longitude and latitude.

I would want to take an array:

```
a = np.array([343.79258065, 343.79096774, 343.78935484])
```

And tile the first value across an array of dims [360, 720], then tile the second value across the same dims [360, 720], and do that for n values in the array (365 times in my case)

A small dim example of this would be (but please note the dims I want below):

```
array([[343.79258065, 343.79258065, 343.79258065, ...],
[343.79096774, 343.79096774, 343.79096774, ...],
[343.78935484, 343.78935484, 343.78935484, ...]])
```

#### The output dimensions

So effectively each value in array `a` would be repeated (tiled?) over an array of dims [360, 720] for 365 layers resulting in a 3D array of dims [365, 360, 720].

It would be great to solve this with `broadcast_to()` if it's possible.  Some links that don't quite do what I want: [Repeating values n times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50579691/repeat-values-an-a-1d-numpy-array-n-times) and [Repeat across multiple dimensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46488056/repeat-a-numpy-array-in-multiple-dimensions-at-once)

Comment: Can you give an example with an object, e.g. `a` above? I get `ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()` when I try use this on an array object.  Shape of the input array is 1D - [365,]

Comment: I'm new to python and clearly need to find time for training in it. If you'll write your broadcast solution as an answer, I can mark it as such.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope I understand your question correctly! I would do this by first reshaping the array into `(N,1,1)`, then expanding each of those 1x1 sub-arrays into the repeated arrays you wanted to be (360, 720) using numpy's [np.repeat](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) function. Here's how I did it:

```
a = np.array([343.79258065, 343.79096774, 343.78935484]).reshape(-1,1,1)
a = np.repeat(a, 360, axis=1)
a = np.repeat(a, 720, axis=2)
print(a.shape)
>> (3, 360, 720)
```

If this isn't what you had in mind, please let me know! Each of the `N` 360x720 arrays contains only repeated instances of the `i`th value of the initial array (`a[i]`), by the way.

Answer (score -1):

I'm adding a `broadcast_to()` answer that a user bizarrely responded with then deleted, because I did ask whether it was possible in the original question. Thanks to both @dsillman2000 and the phantom user.

`np.broadcast_to(a.reshape(-1,1,1), (len(a),360,720))`